# Drop down menu in action bar starts activity automatically

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to create a drop down menu on the action bar with two options. I tried in like in the below code but the first item of the action bar is selected automatically and it starts the new activity.

I'm not getting any error or exception please check what is wrong in my code
     String[] actions = new String[] {
                "Home",
                "Update IMEI"
            };

```
   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, actions);

        /** Enabling dropdown list navigation for the action bar */
        getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);

        /** Defining Navigation listener */
        ActionBar.OnNavigationListener navigationListener = new OnNavigationListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
                //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You selected : " + actions[itemPosition]  , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               switch(itemPosition) {

               case 0:

                    break;

                 case 1:
                    Intent i = new Intent(UserDetail.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Intent ii = new Intent(UserDetail.this, Update_imei.class);
                    startActivity(ii);
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
                }  
                   return false;
            }
        };

        /** Setting dropdown items and item navigation listener for the actionbar */
        getActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(adapter, navigationListener);        
    }    
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope Its help you

```
String[] actions = new String[] {
            "Select Option",
            "Home",
            "Update "
        };
     /** Enabling dropdown list navigation for the action bar */
        getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);

        /** Defining Navigation listener */
        ActionBar.OnNavigationListener navigationListener = new OnNavigationListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
                //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You selected : " + actions[itemPosition]  , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               switch(itemPosition) {

            case 0:

                break;

             case 1:
                Intent i = new Intent(UserDetail.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
            case 2:
                Intent ii = new Intent(UserDetail.this, Update.class);
                startActivity(ii);
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }  
               return false;
            }
        };

        /** Setting dropdown items and item navigation listener for the actionbar */
        getActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(adapter, navigationListener);        
    }
```

Comment: the issue is not coming but case 1 is not working only case 2 is working

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies due to you are checking position variable. When you add your listener to the menu, Android checks the items with position {0,1} with a null id to load method into memory. You can bypass this problem with checking with item id's instead of positions.

Comment: I can give you more detailed example if you show me how you create your menu within your code.